# Resultado AsyncTask

Tags: php, android, json, web-service

Reformulei a pergunta novamente para tentar esclarecer melhor a necessidade da minha situação:

Preciso executar entre asa activity´s a seguinte operação, ao clicar no botão, o aplicativo envia uma informação para uma página php, que a partir dessa informação gera uma Query, valida os dados e cria um arquivo JSON no servidor, então o aplicativo pega este arquivo e le o arquivo JSON.

Atualmente, consigo enviar a informação para um PHP que gera o JSON e tambem consigo ler o arquivo JSON, **mas não consigo executar as duas funções em sequencia no aplicativo**. Alguem tem uma visão de como executar este processo com AsyncTask ou outra classe nativa do Android.

Abaixo o código que eu recupero a informação no arquivo JSON que está salva no servidor.

```
public class BackGroundWorkerItensActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context context;

public BackGroundWorkerItensActivity(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String iddist = params[0];

    String url_receber = "http://minhaurl.com/teste/dados.json";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_receber);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
        String result="";
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("DadosDist", "Erro na lista dos itens!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Intent intentLD = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    Log.i("Vem JSON", s);
    intentLD.putExtra("JSON", s);
    context.startActivity(intentLD);
}
```

Caso não esteja bem detalhado, me informe que irei acrescentar mais informações.

Comment: Você quer gerar um JSON com os dados enviados pelo cliente (do Android)? '-'

Comment: Não, editei minha pergunta para especificar melhor

Comment: Ainda não está claro.

Comment: Ainda está bem ampla. Esses dados gerados estão em um banco de dados ou você extrairia de algum site? O que você já tentou fazer (relação ao código) para gerar esses dados?

Comment: Por exemplo, eu envio o código "1" para uma página php, que irá gerar o arquivo JSON, após gerar o arquivo JSON, irei ler este arquivo pelo aplicativo e apresentar os dados do arquivo para o usuario. Caso exista uma maneira mais fácil de enviar/receber dados entre um aplicativo e webservice, será muito bem vinda a resposta..

Comment: Gabriel da uma olhada aqui, muito mais fácil e vc não precisa nem fazer a async https://github.com/koush/ion#get-json

Comment: não seria só passar Query pro webservice?

Comment: Não, preciso passar apenas um parâmetro para meu PHP que ja faz a Query e receber um JSON de volta do PHP para carregar no App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forma mais simples:

Crie uma classe com nome de conexão da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Conexao {

public static String postDados(String urlUsuario, String parametrosUsuario) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(urlUsuario);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght", "" + Integer.toString(parametrosUsuario.getBytes().length));

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "pt-BR");

        //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Envio
        OutputStreamWriter outPutStream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "utf-8");
        outPutStream.write(parametrosUsuario);
        outPutStream.flush();
        outPutStream.close();
        //Recepção
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));

        String linha;
        StringBuffer resposta = new StringBuffer();

        while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         resposta.append(linha);
            resposta.append('\r');
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        return resposta.toString();

    } catch (Exception erro) {

        return  null;
    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Para chama-lá em seu projeto faça:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

String url = "";
String parametros = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Se fosse um get bastava colocar no final da string url o ?nome=seuget
    url = "url do arquivo php";

    //parâmetros do post
    parametros = "texto=" + "123";

    new main.solicita().execute(url);

   }

    private class solicita extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

        //A string resultado tem os dados vindos do seu arquivo php

    }
}
}
```

Logo depois do seu envio você recebe a resposta no onPostExecute, a resposta está na String resultado. Dessa forma além de enviar e receber de formas mais simples, você diminui a quantidade de códigos no seu projeto

Comment: Cara, eu ia fazer deste modo só faltou encaixar uma coisa na MainActivity.. Obrigado, mitou!!

Comment: @GabrielHenrique vlw kkkkk